# How can I open more than one file and assign it to variables that I haven't defined before?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For example, by opening 3 excel files. I want to work with 3 separately. But how can I do this as I don't know the number of files to open normally?

```
file_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/vehıcle_report.xlsx")


class load_file:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def file_load(self):
        path_ad = os.path.expanduser(self.path)
        path_ex = pathlib.Path(path_ad).suffix
        datac = globals()
        if path_ex == '.csv':
            datac = pd.read_csv(path_ad)
            print('csv dosyası')
        elif path_ex in ('.xlsx', '.xlw', '.xla', '.xml', '.xls'):
            datac = pd.read_excel(path_ad)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Put them in a list.

Comment: Once you've done `pd.read_csv` you have created a `pandas` dataframe.  The file is no longer open or in use.  As with any other Python object that `datac` can be put in a list, or other suitable structure.  Don't skimp on the basic Python study.

Comment: thank you so much. You have given me new perspectives. I will work more.